# ¿Por qué JavaScript se ejecuta diferente en máquinas diferentes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, navegador-web

**PLANTEAMIENTO DEL PROBLEMA**

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Tengo el siguiente problema que ya me tomo todo la tarde intentando resolver.

En una aplicación registro la siguiente función para poder capturar todos los eventos postback generados por ciertas paginas:

```
function ApplicationLoadHandler(sender, args)
{    
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(BeginRequest);
}
```

El código anterior ejecuta la función `BeginRequest()` cada vez que se dispara un evento postBack, en dicho método... necesito evaluar ciertas funciones JavaScript tal como lo muestro en el siguiente código :

**---- código archivo js cancelPostBack.js----**

```
class MyRegExp extends RegExp {
    [Symbol.split](str, limit) {
        var result = RegExp.prototype[Symbol.split].call(this, str, limit);
        return result.map(x => "(" + x + ")");
    }
}

function aContainsB(a, b) {
    return a.indexOf(b) >= 0;
}


function validateEventContainsControlId(Event, controlId) {
    if (aContainsB(Event, controlId)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


debugger;
Sys.Application.add_load(ApplicationLoadHandler);
Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);



function beforeAsyncPostBack(controlId) {


}

function afterAsyncPostBack(sender, e)
{


}

function ApplicationLoadHandler(sender, args)
{

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_initializeRequest(BeginRequest);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(BeginRequest);

}


function BeginRequest(sender, args) {

    debugger; 
    var prm1 = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    var prm2 = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    var controlId = "";
    var ReadFingerPrint = false;
    var elemntsToBreak = ["btnRefresh","btnCancelar","btn_grabar", "Selector"];

    if (prm2._activeElement.type === "text" || prm2._activeElement.type === "checkbox" || prm2._activeElement.type === "image" || prm2._activeElement.type === "submit") {

        if (prm2._activeElement.computedRole !== "button")
            return;
    }

    if (prm1.get_isInAsyncPostBack() || prm2._postBackSettings.async)
    {

        if (validateEventContainsControlId(args.get_postBackElement().id, "btnExport")
            ||
            validateEventContainsControlId(args.get_postBackElement().id, "btn_buscar")
        )
        {
            prm1.abortPostBack();
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
}

function appl_init(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, args)
    {

        debugger;

        var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        //Event raised when the Async Postback is started.
        //sender.abortPostBack();
        // args.set_cancel(true);

        //Detect whether the request is Async
        var isAsync = sender._postBackSettings.async;

        //Detect Id of the control that caused the postback.
        controlId = sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id;


        //Id of the updatepanel that caused the postback
       // var updatePanelId = sender._postBackSettings.panelID.split('|')[0];

        BeginHandler(controlId);
    });

    prm.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
}

function BeginHandler(controlId) {
    debugger;

    beforeAsyncPostBack(controlId);
}

function EndHandler(sender, e) {
    debugger;

    afterAsyncPostBack(sender, e);
}
```

**------ versión simplificada de mi pagina asp ------- ****

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Consulta_Nutricion.aspx.vb" Inherits="Consulta_Nutricion" ValidateRequest="false" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">

    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />

    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/Custom-Cs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ScriptMode="Release">

        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/cancelPostBack.js" />
        </Scripts>

    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="ficha" runat="server">


        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%--ENCABEZADO--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="controlID" Style="display: none" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="lblnhc" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="lblUsuario" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="lblUnidadAtencion" runat="server" />
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" width="850px" style="text-align: left">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lbl_error" runat="server" CssClass="error"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="theader" colspan="4">Consulta Nutrición</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100px; background-color: #5d7b9d; padding-left: 8px; color: #ffffff;">NHC:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 270px; background-color: #e9ecf1">
                            <table id="tblNHC" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nhc" runat="server" CssClass="NHC" MaxLength="7" Width="64px"
                                            TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_buscar" runat="server" ToolTip="BUSCAR" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/magnify-clip.png" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 100px; background-color: #5d7b9d; padding-left: 8px; color: #ffffff;">Género:
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/shim.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/websdk.client.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fingerprint.sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/identapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modalwindow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/beforeCancelPostBack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[name*='btn_buscar']").on('click', function (e) {
            debugger;

            $("input[name*='lblnhc']")[0].value = $("input[name*='txt_nhc']")[0].value;
        });

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }, false);

    </script>


</asp:Content>
```

Es aquí donde se genera mi problema. Esto es lo que sucede; en algunas maquinas la propiedad `prm2._activeElement.computedRole` si devuelve un valor esperado ("button"), tal como lo mostrare en la siguiente imagen, en donde evaluó si la propiedad es distinta de button :

[image: imagen de la función ejecutándose en modo debug en chrome]

Es aquí donde inicia mi problema, ya que en otras maquinas de la red, la misma propiedad (`prm2._activeElement.computedRole`) solamente devuelve "undefined".

**LO QUE HE INTENTADO PARA RESOLVER HASTA EL MOMENTO**

Después de revisar las versión de los archivos jquery y javascript en las maquinas donde ocurrían estas diferencias (las de las propiedades `prm2._activeElement.computedRole` ) constate que eran las mismas tanto en la que si devolvía la computedRole == "button" como donde devuelve
"undefined", estas versiones son las que se están ejecutando:

jquery :

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
"3.2.1"

javascript : 1.7
```

Para evitar que los navegadores utilicen los archivos del cache y obligar a que los descarguen de mi server coloque el siguiente código en el encabezado de la pagina en cuestión:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```

Sin embargo, continuo obteniendo el mismo problema.

¿Por qué javascript devuelve diferentes propiedades al ejecutarse en diferentes maquinas, si ambas ejecutan la misma versión de los archivos js ?

Podría alguien por favor darme alguna luz sobre por donde debería ir para resolver este problema.

Comment: ¿Todos los navegadores son iguales? ¿Qué navegadores usas? ¿Qué archivos javascript estás cargando en ellos? ¿Has limpiado la caché de los navegadores para evitar que se esté usando una versión anterior de tu script?

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia. Todos los navegadores son chrome 71.0.3578.98, los demás cuestionamientos los plantee en la pregunta, pero si, si limpie el cache.

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow, en la pregunta se plantea que agregue  el código al que te refieres en la pagina (asp) para evitar usar el cache de el navegador cliente.

Comment: En la pregunta explicas que usas unas etiquetas HTML para evitar que se guarde en caché del navegador el HTML, pero para los scripts Javascript que se incluyan (en tu caso `cancelPostBack.js`) esas cabeceras son indiferentes. En cualquier caso, sin un HTML/JS completo con el que reproducir el problema no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: el undefined puede ser logico por la simple razon que se ejecuta primero tu Js y luego carga el DOM HTML , o incluso esas funciones(que las desconozco) hacen un .bind() y pierden el contexto

Comment: verifica que agregas la libreria al final del HTML para evitar el undefined

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, si sirve de algo ....edite mi pregunta para agregar el código del archivo cancelPostBack.js y una versión simplificada de la pagina asp donde se utiliza

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow... intentare la solución que propones ...

Comment: Aunque @JackNavaRow tiene razón cuando habla sobre el orden de carga de los scripts, cuando son funciones que responden a eventos entonces podría estar todo bien. Lo que estoy viendo es que es probable que el problema no sea de javascript, si no de asp y/o webforms. ¿Podrías comprobar que el HTML generado en todos los equipos es el mismo? Deberás darle a "Control+U" y luego guardar (Control+S). No conozco webforms, por lo que no sé si hay algo mal en su uso en asp.net, sin el programa que genera el HTML a partir de tu ASP no podré ayudarte con temas relacionados con javascript.

Comment: Realice la comparación de dos HTML de la misma pagina generados por dos distintas maquinas; que cambio significativos debería notar  al comparar los HTML generados ?  Ya que al hacer una comparación con una herramienta para comparar archivos (beyond compare)  los archivos son significativamente diferentes.